# Unable to deploy new versions in App-Engine. Error com.google.api.Service.hasQuota()

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Errors appeared some week ago but it happened rarely and uploading new versions fixed it.
Now it happens for every version and I'm unable to deploy new ones. Nothing has changed in the project configuration, dependencies versions or google cloud configurations.

Exception after deploying, every call throws it:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.Service.hasQuota()Z
    at com.google.api.control.model.MethodRegistry.extractQuota(MethodRegistry.java:290)
    at com.google.api.control.model.MethodRegistry.<init>(MethodRegistry.java:72)
    at com.google.api.control.ConfigFilter.init(ConfigFilter.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:881)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doStart(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:240)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:178)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:120)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:782)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:745)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:715)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure your Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) is not outdated? Try `glcoud update components`.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Fernandez Did you find a solution? As I have started coming into the same issue.

Comment: Issue created with Google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184183409

Comment: Hi @vitooh I tried updating it already, but it didn't work. Still no solution

Comment: Hi @DanielJ, I managed to fix it updating dependencies. Specifically these:
endpoints-management-control-appengine and
endpoints-framework-auth to version 1.0.11+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it updating dependencies:

```
endpoints-management-control-appengine: 1.0.11+
endpoints-framework-auth: 1.0.11+
protobuf-java: 3.11.0+
```